# R how to overlay in geom_tile?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I created a relatively simple heatmap using geom_tile in ggplot2. It's just a small matrix of data as colored boxes.

On the y axis i represented people (using an identification number starting from 1 to 1000) and on x axis time in hours.

The first df represents people occupancy patters or when they are at home/ when they are away from home. For example it shows the timings when id1 is at home or when is away from home.

The second df2 represent the same people behaviour regarding to behaviour use of devices.For example it shows the timings when id1 is using a device and when he is not using any device.

Now I tried to represent one the same plot the occupancy and device use patterns for the id's. For example I would like to represent when id is at home and using a device in one plot.

Can such a thing be done?

Data from df:

```
structure(list(id = 1:6, variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", 
"04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", 
"06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", 
"07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", 
"08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", 
"09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", 
"10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", 
"11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", 
"13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", 
"14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", 
"15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", 
"16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", 
"17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", 
"18:50", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", 
"20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", 
"21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", 
"22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", 
"23:30", "23:40", "23:50", "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", 
"00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", 
"01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", 
"03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", "03:50"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c("Did not used device", "Did not used device", "Did not used device", 
    "Did not used device", "Did not used device", "Did not used device"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

From this data I created the above plot

[image]

Data from df2:

```
structure(list(id = 1:6, variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("04:00", "04:10", "04:20", "04:30", "04:40", 
"04:50", "05:00", "05:10", "05:20", "05:30", "05:40", "05:50", 
"06:00", "06:10", "06:20", "06:30", "06:40", "06:50", "07:00", 
"07:10", "07:20", "07:30", "07:40", "07:50", "08:00", "08:10", 
"08:20", "08:30", "08:40", "08:50", "09:00", "09:10", "09:20", 
"09:30", "09:40", "09:50", "10:00", "10:10", "10:20", "10:30", 
"10:40", "10:50", "11:00", "11:10", "11:20", "11:30", "11:40", 
"11:50", "12:00", "12:10", "12:20", "12:30", "12:40", "12:50", 
"13:00", "13:10", "13:20", "13:30", "13:40", "13:50", "14:00", 
"14:10", "14:20", "14:30", "14:40", "14:50", "15:00", "15:10", 
"15:20", "15:30", "15:40", "15:50", "16:00", "16:10", "16:20", 
"16:30", "16:40", "16:50", "17:00", "17:10", "17:20", "17:30", 
"17:40", "17:50", "18:00", "18:10", "18:20", "18:30", "18:40", 
"18:50", "19:00", "19:10", "19:20", "19:30", "19:40", "19:50", 
"20:00", "20:10", "20:20", "20:30", "20:40", "20:50", "21:00", 
"21:10", "21:20", "21:30", "21:40", "21:50", "22:00", "22:10", 
"22:20", "22:30", "22:40", "22:50", "23:00", "23:10", "23:20", 
"23:30", "23:40", "23:50", "00:00", "00:10", "00:20", "00:30", 
"00:40", "00:50", "01:00", "01:10", "01:20", "01:30", "01:40", 
"01:50", "02:00", "02:10", "02:20", "02:30", "02:40", "02:50", 
"03:00", "03:10", "03:20", "03:30", "03:40", "03:50"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c("At home", "At home", "At home", "Not Athome", 
    "At home", "At home")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using this data I created the above plot;
[image]

I want to overlay the 2 plots to show when Id 1 is at home and using a device.Code that used to overlay the plots:

```
ggplot( df2_melted_modified , aes(x = variable, y = id, fill= value)) + 
  scale_x_discrete( name= "Time (hours)") + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(-0, 0)) +  
  geom_tile() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(1, "mm"), axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
  labs(x="Time", y ="Respondents indentification number", fill="Behaviour")
```

This is the plot that I created, I don't understand why the use of device is not highlighted? I help is welcomed!

[image]

I would like to have a plot like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found you example data a little bit hard to recapitulate your problem, so I hope you don't mind I created my own (see end of post)

It would probably be easiest if you have the data in one data.frame with shared x/y values and the at home / using device variables as two columns.

The easiest way is to just use `interaction` between those columns:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Var2, Var1)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = interaction(athome, usedev)))
```

[image]

A slightly more manual way is to make two layers for your at home / use device variables and set one layer to (semi-) transparent:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Var2, Var1)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = athome)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = usedev)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("At home" = "red",
                               "Not at home" = "white",
                               "Not using device" = "transparent",
                               "Using device" = "#0000FF88"))
```

[image]

Making fake data:

```
m <- matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 24)

athome <- t(apply(m, 1, function(x) {
  i <- rpois(1, 10)
  x[i:pmin(rpois(1, 10), 24)] <- 1
  x
}))

usedev <- t(apply(m, 1, function(x) {
  i <- rpois(1, 11)
  x[i:pmin(rpois(1, 11), 24)] <- 1
  x
}))

df <- cbind(
  reshape2::melt(athome, value.name = "athome"),
  usedev = reshape2::melt(usedev)[,-c(1:2)]
)

df$athome <- factor(df$athome)
levels(df$athome) <- c("Not at home", "At home")

df$usedev <- factor(df$usedev)
levels(df$usedev) <- c("Not using device", "Using device")
```